# Programs to help beginners to practice Chess

Tags: software, beginner

I'm a beginner in chess and I want to get better at this game. I was wondering if there are some programs that help you to practice your game. For example: practicing the openings, that contains checkmate puzzles, etc.

Answer (score 4):

[Chess Tempo](http://chesstempo.com/chess-openings.html) has a great section on openings used by real players as well as statistics regarding the openings(player win %, draw %, opponent win %, etc.) and also an interactive board which lets you step through each move of the opening.

Answer (score 3):

There are some great resources available both online and for download (programs or apps). Some worth checking out:

[chess.com](https://www.chess.com/) - free (for a basic account, paid for additional features like videos and "chess mentor", which have been well worth the money for me).

[chesstempo.com](https://chesstempo.com/) - free - mostly tactics problems, also endgames, database, etc.

[Lucas Chess](https://www-lucaschess.rhcloud.com/) - a free chess program with various engines included. Has tons of features, including tactics, openings, various types of "competition" against the computer, mate practice, etc...

That should definitely get you started, and some additional future resources include the "[chess tutor](http://www.shredderchess.com/chess-software/chess-tutor.html)" programs from Shredder Chess and the Peshka software which has various training modules (lots of interesting and useful stuff, but a bit of a clunky interface).

There are also lots of IOS/android apps available. Stockfish is a free chess engine, and if you don't mind paying a few bucks, Shredder or Hiarcs are both excellent.

Good luck!

Comment: I like the idea to play on mi Ipad or Iphone and I don't mind to pay some bucks. Which app do you recomend me? (keep in mind that I'm a beginner)

Comment: I like Hiarcs for the iPad - it's not cheap at $10, but it plays very "human like" chess at lower ratings.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a new version has been made in a while, but there used to be Chessmaster. Chessok offers a number of programs, and some of them have been converted to Android apps. This includes some tactics programs, and a guide that is supposed to take a player from beginner to club player.

Chesstempo.com, as mentioned, is a great site to work on tactics and they have been adding other features. lichess.org has a training feature where it gives you an opening position and you have to pick a certain number of good moves in the position. I'm not sure if there is a site that actually drills you on openings though.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of apps on [chessok.com](http://chessok.com): training apps (for PC) for training openings, middle games, ending and more for any chess player from beginner to advanced player.

Answer (score 1):

I have started adding training UIs into my online Javascript engine.  Currently just a mate-in-one trainer:-

http://op12no2.me/toys/lozza

Please do feel free to say how it can be improved.

PS: I find it harder than it sounds!